# Bayesian network query

Tags: probability, graph-theory, bayesian-network

I am having a bit of trouble with something that I imagine is fairly easy.
[image]

I am wondering how to get the probability of alarm, JohnCalls, and MaryCalls if they have no prior knowledge of their parents.

I assumed P(A) = P(A|B,E)*P(A|B,!E)...=.95*.94*.29*.001 = .00026

However, I can't make sense of this, as that is even lower than if there were no Burglary or Earthquake at all.  Likewise with JohnCalls, if JohnCalls even when there is no alarm 5% of the time, .90*.05 < 5% and that makes no sense to me.

I assume there is an easy solution to this, so thank you for your patience.

Also, I am trying to create this in a java program, and am having a bit of difficulty.  Can anyone recommend a good tutorial for a problem like this that will help me create a program in which I could query anything to do with a graph like this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can add something to start an answer, but I'm no Java expert, sorry!

$$\mathsf P(A) = \sum\limits_{b\in\{B,!B\}}\sum\limits_{e\in\{E,!E\}} P(A, b, e)$$

This is because of the partition rule of probability (more of an explanation is [here](http://jeremykun.com/2013/03/28/conditional-partitioned-probability-a-primer/) ).   (Also known as the Total Probability Theorem, or Law of Total Probability.)

Recall from conditional probability: $\mathsf P(A, B) = \mathsf P(A \mid B)\cdot\mathsf P(B)$ .

So $\mathsf P(A, B, E) = \mathsf P(A\mid B,E)\cdot\mathsf P(B,E)$, for example.

Which means:

$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A) = & {\mathsf P(A \mid B, E)\mathsf P(B, E) + \mathsf P(A\mid B, !E)\mathsf P(B, !E) \\ + \mathsf P(A\mid !B, E)\mathsf P(!B, E) + \mathsf P(A \mid !B, !E)\mathsf P(!B, !E)}\end{align}$$

This is because the there are 4 ways in which A can happen. A can happen if events B and E happen, if B happens and not E, if E happens and not B, or if neither of them happen.

Working that out (and assuming B and E are independent), we have:

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A) = & (0.95\cdot 0.001\cdot 0.002) + (0.94\cdot 0.001\cdot 0.998) + (0.29\cdot 0.999\cdot 0.002) + (0.001\cdot 0.999\cdot 0.998)\\[1ex] = & 0.002516442 \end{align}$

Using the same principle, you can get P(John calls) and P(Mary calls):

$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(\text{John calls}) = & \mathsf P(\text{John calls}\mid A)\mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(\text{John calls}\mid !A)\mathsf P(!A) \\[1ex] = & 0.9\cdot 0.002516442 + 0.05\cdot (1-0.002516442) \\[1ex] = & 0.052\text{(truncating)} \\[3ex] \mathsf P(\text{Mary calls}) = &\mathsf P(\text{Mary calls}\mid A)\mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(\text{Mary calls}\mid !A)\mathsf P(!A)\\[1ex] =  & 0.7\cdot 0.002516442 + 0.01\cdot (1-0.002516442) \\[1ex] = & 0.012\text{(truncating)}\end{align}$$

Hope that helps on the probability side of things! Does anyone see an error with this?

Comment: This was more than I could have hoped! Thanks for the great answer and the link.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Graham!